# Trying to pack a custom react library package by webpack made by me written in ts but it says interface and type is not recognised

Tags: typescript

I have done npm init to initialise the library from scratch and after writing the code I am facing the problem that isnt alowing me to pack the files using webpack. Now note al files are in .ts or .tsx . I wrote a webpack config and included all the files for it i wrote the tsconfig too. they are as follows

```
Webpack:
```

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  
  mode: 'production',
  entry: path.join(__dirname,'./src/index.js'), // Replace 'index.ts' with your actual entry point TypeScript file.
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'), // Replace 'dist' with the desired output directory.
    filename: 'component.js',
    clean: true,
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['','.tsx','.ts', '.jsx','js', '.json'], // Add '.ts' to the extensions so Webpack can resolve TypeScript files.
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(ts|tsx)?$/,
        use: 'babel-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/,
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

ts.config.json:

```
{
  "extends":"@tsconfig/recommended/tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "moduleResolution": "Bundler",                     /* Specify how TypeScript looks up a file from a given module specifier. */
    "baseUrl": "./src",                                  /* Specify the base directory to resolve non-relative module names. */
    "paths": {
      "*": ["*", "src/*"]
    },                                      /* Specify a set of entries that re-map imports to additional lookup locations. */
    "esModuleInterop": true,                             /* Emit additional JavaScript to ease support for importing CommonJS modules. This enables 'allowSyntheticDefaultImports' for type compatibility. */included with TypeScript. */
    "skipLibCheck": true                                 /* Skip type checking all .d.ts files. */
  }
  
}
{ "name": "@cardformatdisplayerfromapi/ui", "version": "1.0.0", "description": "UI component for a card view of data in the form of array of objects, which is the format for response.data format from backend/pi servers.", "main": "./src/index.ts", "files": [ "src/**/*" ], "scripts": { "test": "echo "Error: no test specified" && exit 1", "build": "webpack --mode production" }, "author": "NewCardcOmponent", "license": "ISC", "dependencies": { "@mui/material": "^5.14.2", "react": "^18.2.0", "type-scripts": "^1.2.1" }, "devDependencies": { "@babel/core": "^7.22.9", "@babel/preset-env": "^7.22.9", "@babel/preset-react": "^7.22.5", "@babel/preset-typescript": "^7.22.5", "@tsconfig/recommended": "^1.0.2", "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^6.2.0", "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^6.2.0", "babel-loader": "^9.1.3", "eslint": "^8.45.0", "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.33.0", "ts-loader": "^9.4.4", "typescript": "^5.1.6", "webpack": "^5.88.2", "webpack-cli": "^5.1.4" }, "keywords": [] }
```

and after running "npx webpack --mode development" t gives me following error :

```
asset component.js 28.1 KiB [compared for emit] (name: main)
runtime modules 937 bytes 4 modules
cacheable modules 211 bytes
  ./src/index.js 94 bytes [built] [code generated]
  ./src/cardcomponent.tsx 39 bytes [built] [code generated] [1 error]
  ./src/cardloader.tsx 39 bytes [built] [code generated] [1 error]
  ./src/cardmapper.tsx 39 bytes [built] [code generated] [1 error]

ERROR in ./src/cardcomponent.tsx
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
SyntaxError: C:\Users\anirbans\Desktop\New folder\poc\combined_projects\src\cardcomponent.tsx: Unexpected token, expected "," (7:28)

   5 |
   6 |
>  7 | function Cardcomponent(props:Person[]) {
     |                             ^
   8 |
   9 |   return (
  10 |    <OutlinedCardMapped data={props}/>


ERROR in ./src/cardloader.tsx
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
SyntaxError: C:\Users\anirbans\Desktop\New folder\poc\combined_projects\src\cardloader.tsx: Missing initializer in const declaration. (10:17)  

   8 |
   9 |
> 10 | export const data: Person[] = [
     |                  ^
  11 |   { firstName: "John", phone: 30, email: "New York" },
  12 |   { firstName: "Alice", phone: 25, email: "Los Angeles" },
  13 |   { firstName: "Anirban", phone: 35, email: "Chicago" },


ERROR in ./src/cardmapper.tsx
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
SyntaxError: C:\Users\anirbans\Desktop\New folder\poc\combined_projects\src\cardmapper.tsx: Unexpected reserved word 'interface'. (5:0)        

  3 | import { Person } from './cardloader';
  4 |
> 5 | interface comp  {
    | ^
  6 |     data: Person[]; // Declare the prop "data" with type Person[]
  7 |   };
  8 |
```

and package .json is :

```
{ "name": "@cardformatdisplayerfromapi/ui", "version": "1.0.0", "description": "UI component for a card view of data in the form of array of objects, which is the format for response.data format from backend/pi servers.", "main": "./src/index.ts", "files": [ "src/**/*" ], "scripts": { "test": "echo "Error: no test specified" && exit 1", "build": "webpack --mode production" }, "author": "NewCardcOmponent", "license": "ISC", "dependencies": { "@mui/material": "^5.14.2", "react": "^18.2.0", "type-scripts": "^1.2.1" }, "devDependencies": { "@babel/core": "^7.22.9", "@babel/preset-env": "^7.22.9", "@babel/preset-react": "^7.22.5", "@babel/preset-typescript": "^7.22.5", "@tsconfig/recommended": "^1.0.2", "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^6.2.0", "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^6.2.0", "babel-loader": "^9.1.3", "eslint": "^8.45.0", "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.33.0", "ts-loader": "^9.4.4", "typescript": "^5.1.6", "webpack": "^5.88.2", "webpack-cli": "^5.1.4" }, "keywords": [] }
```